# Public folder not visible from front end Exchange 2003 Server

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, public-folders

I have a public folder that does not receive emails when the emails are sent via the Front-End Exchange Servers.  When I go into the System Manager on the Front-End I don't see this particular public folder listed under the Public Folders.  However, I do see it listed from the Back-End server. I see the emails that are not making it to the public folder listed in the local delivery queue on the front end server and they are in a retry state.

Does anyone know how I might troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the folder hierarchy is out of sync between the machines. As a first step, I'd try doing a "Send Hierarchy" (see [How to Replicate Public Folder Data Manually](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997802(EXCHG.65).aspx) for some details) first.

I've seen instances where a front-end server believed it had a public store, evne though it didn't. You might use ADSIEDIT to look at this. Drill into the Configuration partition, then "Services", "Microsoft Exchange", your organization's name, "Administrative Groups", the AG the front-end server is in, "Servers", and the server itself. If it has an "Information Store" node, drill into there, then into each storage group, looking for any objects of class msExchPublicMDB.

Assuming you're certain that you're deleting the right thing, you can try deleting an erroneous public information store, if you find one, and that may improve the behavior. Obviously, don't do this without being sure that you're not going to delete something you need.

Comment: Okay, I will have a go with this on Monday. I saw the sync Hierarchy and it seemed like the right thing to do, but it also seemed like the sort of thing I didn't want to click without knowing the implications :-)  As an aside, on one of the other front end servers I don't see any public folders but instead get an error about "invalid HTTP format...check Headers" which makes no sense to me, but I will tackle that one second.